# What is my number?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, acrostic

Been thinking about doing a puzzle like this for awhile. Hopefully this isn't too easy.

> gather the clues to figure it out
>
> answer my question, with no doubts
>
> begin at the start, work your way down
>
> backtrack a bit, then all the way now
>
> only one it could be, please explain how

**What is the number?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume

> your number is 1092

Because

> The acrostic is gabbo as you work your way down

And

> you are gabbo1092, the only one it could be!

Comment: lol, right after I fgitw someone else, I get fgitw’ed. karma.

Comment: You got it. There was also a clue in the 3rd and 4th line but I had a feeling they might get overlooked by the more obvious clue.

Answer (score 2):

idk if this is the answer, but

> 1092

because

> the acrostic is “gabbo”, as in the OP’s username

and

> the number that immediately succeeds that in the OP’s username is 1092.